# If $a$ is an irrational number, is it possible $\{u_na\}u_n^k\mapsto 0$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, elementary-number-theory

Let $k\geq1$ be an integer, let $a$ be a positive irrational number. Can we find a sequence $(u_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\in\mathbb{N}^{\mathbb{N}}$ such that $u_n \to \infty$ when $n\to \infty$ and $\{u_na\}u_n^k\to 0$ when $n\to \infty$.

Here, for all $x \in \mathbb{R}^+$, $\{x\}=x-\lfloor x \rfloor.$

Comment: What is $a$? Here?

Comment: @ZelosMalum a positive irrational number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a question about quality of rational approximations, which can be equivalently stated as: For an irrational $a$ and integer $k$ and $\varepsilon>0$ do there exist infinitely many pairs of integers $b,c$ such $0<ba-c<\frac{\varepsilon}{b^k}$ (I leave the equivalence for you)? If we slightly relax this condition to $|ba-c|<\frac{1}{b^k}$, or equivalently
$$\left|a-\frac{c}{b}\right|<\frac{\varepsilon}{b^{k+1}},$$
we get a typical problem in a very wide theory of [Diophantine approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diophantine_approximation). Let me state a few results of this theory.

First of all, there needn't always exist infinitely many such $b,c$. The numbers for which this is true are called [Liouville numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville_number), and, in certain sense,  they are very rare among real numbers. Indeed, for most (in the same sense) numbers, even taking $k=1+\epsilon$ (for any $\epsilon>0$) won't give us infinitely many $b,c$. The celebrated [Roth's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roth%27s_theorem) states that you won't find infinitely many such approximations for any $k>1$, when $a$ is an irrational algebraic number. [Liouville's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville_number#Liouville_numbers_and_transcendence) is a weaker but far more elementary statement of this sort (if $a$ is algebraic irrational of degree $n$, then there will be finitely many approximations with $k>n-1$), so if you want to learn more about the topic, this theorem is the place to start.

Now, there are also some positive results. [Dirichlet's approximation theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_approximation_theorem) states that for $k=1,\varepsilon=1$ there are infinitely many good rational approximations. Variation of the argument shows that we can even guarantee $0<ba-c<\frac{1}{b}$, which is the setting of your question. [Hurwitz's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hurwitz%27s_theorem_(number_theory)) improves this $\varepsilon$ to $\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}$, but I am unsure whether a variation of the argument gives us positive differences (but it should). Hurwitz's theorem is, in a way, optimal - if you take $a=\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}$, then for no $\varepsilon<\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}$ you will have infinitely many good rational approximations.

For the last result I want to mention I couldn't find a reference, but I am positive it's true, is that for most of real numbers (again, in certain formal sense), for any $\varepsilon>0$ there are infinitely many good rational approximations with $k=1$. Therefore for most $a$ you indeed can find a sequence $b_n,c_n$ such that $|b_na-c_n|b_n\rightarrow 0$. I am fairly sure we can find these $b_n,c_n$ so that $0<b_na-c_n$, which would give us $\{b_na\}b_n\rightarrow 0$, but I cannot provide a reference either.

So to sum up: for most of the numbers the answer is no for $k>1$ and yes for $k=1$, but there are numbers for which the answers is yes for all $k$, and there are numbers for which the answer is no even for $k=1$.